# Clear all lru_cache in Python

Tags: python, caching, lru

I have functions in python that have caches with lru_cache e.g.

```
 @lru_cache(maxsize=None)
 def my_function():
    ...
```

While i can individually clear the caches with e.g. `my_function.cache_clear()` is there any way of clearing the caches of every function at once? [I was thinking that maybe there is a way of returning all function names loaded in memory, and then loop over them clearing the cache from each].

I'm specifically looking to implement as part of a fall-back, for cases where say 90% of the memory on my machine gets used.

Comment: Yes, the decorated function now has the method `my_function.cache_clear()`. You can also get stats with `my_function.cache_info()`. See [`lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functools.html?highlight=lru#functools.lru_cache)

Comment: @AChampion - sure, aware of both of those, question though is rather is there a way of applying those methods to every decorated functions (i.e. clear *all* the lru_cache's).

Comment: No, there is no simple way to clear all decorated function caches, they are all independent. You could create a registry of all those functions and then iterate through them to clear.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create a modified decorator which also takes note of the cached functions:

```
cached_functions = []

def clearable_lru_cache(*args, **kwargs):
    def decorator(func):
        func = lru_cache(*args, **kwargs)(func)
        cached_functions.append(func)
        return func

    return decorator

def clear_all_cached_functions():
    for func in cached_functions:
        func.cache_clear()
```

If you really want you can also use monkey patching to replace the original decorator.

Test:

```
@clearable_lru_cache()
def foo(x):
    print('foo', x)

@clearable_lru_cache()
def bar(x):
    print('bar', x)

for i in [1, 2]:
    for j in [1, 2]:
        print('Calling functions')
        for k in [1, 2, 3]:
            for f in [foo, bar]:
                f(k)
        print('Functions called - if you saw nothing they were cached')
    print('Clearing cache')
    clear_all_cached_functions()
```

Output:

```
Calling functions
foo 1
bar 1
foo 2
bar 2
foo 3
bar 3
Functions called - if you saw nothing they were cached
Calling functions
Functions called - if you saw nothing they were cached
Clearing cache
Calling functions
foo 1
bar 1
foo 2
bar 2
foo 3
bar 3
Functions called - if you saw nothing they were cached
Calling functions
Functions called - if you saw nothing they were cached
Clearing cache
```

Answer (score 19):

> maybe there is a way of returning all function
>   names loaded in memory, and then loop over them clearing the cache
>   from each

Yes that is possible as well:

```
import functools
import gc

gc.collect()
wrappers = [
    a for a in gc.get_objects() 
    if isinstance(a, functools._lru_cache_wrapper)]

for wrapper in wrappers:
    wrapper.cache_clear()
```

> I'm specifically looking to implement as part of a fall-back, for
>   cases where say 90% of the memory on my machine gets used.

This is code you will probably not use under normal circumstances, but can be useful for debugging.

In my particular case I wanted to clear some [dangling file handles from matplotlib](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/commit/349762b8d2fba9638746e6ed1c8d237a925561ec) (in order to focus on my own loose file handles), so it was not possible to use the solution by Alex Hall.

Comment: Inheriting a codebase that was so hard to test because of the reliance on lru_caches that shared state between tests.